# logrotate compress files as a different user than specified

Tags: logrotate

Using the following logrotate config file, rotated files are being chowned to the specified user but not compressed ones.

```
    /var/log/file.log {
           notifempty
            missingok
            size 1M
            rotate 30
            delaycompres
            create 0600 user group
            compress 
            }
```

Is this an expected behaviour from **logrotate** and if yes how can I tweak it to compress the logs with the correct permissions and user:group ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'create' option tell logrotate to create new log file with specified permission before running postrotete script. It does not affect on permissions of compressed files. You may try this:

```
lastscript
chown user:group /var/log/yourapp/*.gz
chmod -R 0600 /var/log/yourapp/*.gz
endscript
```

Comment: So this is expected behaviour, I was hoping to not use custom scripts/commands inside logrotate configs.